# Automatically closing DBHelper after Cursor closed

Tags: android, cursor, sqliteopenhelper

I have a method like this:

```
public Cursor getData(){
    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper();
    Cursor c;
    ...
    return c;
}
```

How can I define an event handler for closing DBHelper after closing Cursor(c) outside of this method?

Answer (score 0):

You could make DBHelper global:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity {
    DBHelper helper;

    public Cursor getData() {
        helper = new DBHelper();
        Cursor c;
        ...
        return c;
    }

    private void closeDBC() {
       c.close();
       if(helper != null) helper.close();
    }
}
```

Edit:
I usually open my DBHelper in `onCreate` and close it in `onPause` - Dunno if that is good practice but it works for me

Comment: Thanks, but when using ContentProvider, your solution is not useful. Suppose that this method acts as an interface method between apks.